# Warn user of unsaved data in JSF

Tags: jsf

I want to warn user of any unsaved data in a form before he/she clicks on a link to navigate away from the current page, without saving.
   What would be a better approach to achieve this in JSF, so that this check is done at one single place for all pages.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

The standard JSF implementation doesn't provide facilities for this out the box. Besides, this is more a client side issue than a server side issue, so you'll really need to grab a client side language for this such as JavaScript. Since writing crossbrowser compatible JavaScript code for this particular functional requirement isn't exactly trivial, you'd like to use a JavaScript library for this which takes this into account, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Here's a complete kickoff example of how you could achieve this with help of jQuery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Set the unload message whenever any input element get changed.
        $(':input').change(function() {
            setConfirmUnload(true);
        });

        // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly.
        $('form').submit(function() {
            setConfirmUnload(false);
        });
    });

    function setConfirmUnload(on) {
        var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?";
        window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null;
    }
</script>
```

Just paste this in your `<head>` template (and preferably also refactor that raw `<script>` code into its own `.js` file as well which you include by `src` attribute) and it'll work regardless of the page you have.

Comment: If you happen to be using PrimeFaces, eliminate the script that loads jQuery. jQuery is bundled with PrimeFaces and is loaded when when you use PrimeFaces components on a page. See [Adding jQuery to PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeErrors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add an onclick to all of your links. With jQuery you could do the following:

```
$($('a').click(function(){
    if(unsavedWork){
        return confirm("You have not saved your work, would you like to leave anyway?");
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}););
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JSF template and you want the message on a **specific page** and not when leaving **every page** you can do:

**1)** Set an id to the body element in your template:

```
    <h:body id="mainBody">
    </h:body>
```

**2)** Use such id in the **specific window or view** where you want the on before leaving message:

```
    <script>
        document.getElementById("mainBody").onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            return true;
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Although the original question asks about validation for all forms in a JSF website, the solution that I propose helps when a developer wants  a before-leaving warning only for some forms and not for all of them.

Comment: But there is nothing related to 'changes' in inputs in ypur answer.