# jsf onbeforeunload runs with submit always

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I followed this excellent example [Warn user of unsaved data in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5709356/1596104)

The results are almost perfect.

I get the prompt during submit always.  How does this example turn off the message?  I thought the $form.submit did that but it doesn't work for me.  What did I miss?

My page submits like this:

```
<h:commandLink value="Save" action="#{report.saveReport}" >
    <f:param name="id" value="#{report.id}"/>
    <f:param name="name" value="#{report.name}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

The commandLink is a link, may not perform a "standard" submit. There is *probably* javascript which generates the submit. This is *probably* circumventing the logic for the submit code. Bind the form submit event to the onclick for the link, and everything *should* work fine.