# jsf page not rendered with template

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, templating

Currently I have two pages and one template:

```
myapp (war)
|-myTemplate.xhtml  //yes i know, the template is in the main folder :(
|-page1.xhtml
|-folder    
    |--page2.xhtml
```

page1 and page2 has the same structure

So, when i access to the page1 the jsf template renders pretty well, but, when i tried look at the page2, everything looks distorted. The template is not working in that case.

web.xml has the 'url pattern' in this way:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

EDIT: the page is pretty simple, the template is much more elaborated

**page1.xhtml and page2.xhtml** :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                template="./mainTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h1>
            <h:outputText value="#{i18n['cc.title']}"/>
        </h1>

        <h:form id="form">           
           <!-- outputLabels, inputTexts... -->
        </h:form>  

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**template.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:loadBundle var="i18n" basename="co.gov.rnec.srcw.languages.Mensajes"/>
    <f:loadBundle var="i18nDefuncion" basename="co.gov.rnec.srcw.languages.MensajesDefuncion"/>
    <f:loadBundle var="i18nMatrimonio" basename="co.gov.rnec.srcw.languages.MensajesMatrimonio"/>
    <f:loadBundle var="i18nNacimiento" basename="co.gov.rnec.srcw.languages.MensajesNacimiento"/>
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link href="styles/styles_ani.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="styles/form_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="styles/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>#{i18n['srcw.titulo']}</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general/general.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general/fechas.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general/frmvalidaciones.js"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body onload="getHora();" >

        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="floatleft">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/logorneclittle.jpg" alt="Registraduria Nacional del Estado Civil" name="Logo" width="145" height="90" id="Insert_logo" style="background-color: #8090AB; display:block;" /></a> 
                </div>
                <div class="floatleft">
                    <p class="size50">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p class="ani-verdanagriscatorce size50"><h:outputText value="#{i18n['main.titulo.titulo']}" escape="false"/></p>
                    <p class="ani-verdanaverdedieciseis size50"><h:outputText value="#{i18n['main.titulo.subtitulo1']}" escape="false"/></p>
                    <p class="ani-verdanagriscatorce size50"><h:outputText value="#{i18n['main.titulo.subtitulo2']}" escape="false"/></p>
                    <div class="floatleft"><p><a href="logout.jsp">#{i18n["main.titulo.salida"]}</a></p></div>
                    <div class="floatleft"><p><a href="cambiaclave.jsp">#{i18n["main.titulo.cambiarclave"]}</a></p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="floatright ani-normalgrisdieztitulo">
                    <p class="size30">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p class="size30">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p class="size30"><h:outputText value="#{i18n['main.label.version']}: #{i18n['srcw.version']}" escape="false"/></p>
                    <p class="size30">#{i18n["main.label.usuario"]}: <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.nombrecompleto} - #{sessionScope.login}" styleClass="capitalized" /></p>
                    <p class="size30">#{i18n["main.label.cargo"]}: <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.grupo}" styleClass="capitalized" /></p>
                    <p class="size30" id="reloj"></p>
                </div>
                <br class="clearfloat"/>
                <div id="menu" class="menu">
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{sessionScope.menuAplicacion}"/>
                </div>
                <!-- end .header -->
            </div>
            <div id="formulario" class="content">
            <!-- a form -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

As you can see page1 has the same structure as page2 (well, obviously i modified the template path accordingly) and there is no message error. Just when access to page2 a malformed page.

Comment: Why aren't you showing how you're referencing/using the template in the page where it failed?

Comment: xhtml's added. Using Tomcat7 + jsf (jar). A big part of the project is based on servlets and we are trying to migrate to jsf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because all your CSS/JS resources are referenced using a folder-relative URI.

For example, those two

```
<link href="styles/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

will actually be downloaded from

```
http://localhost:8080/contextpath/styles/menu.css
http://localhost:8080/contextpath/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
```

when you open `page1.xhtml`.

However, when you open `folder/page2.xhtml`, the browser will attempt to download them from

```
http://localhost:8080/contextpath/folder/styles/menu.css
http://localhost:8080/contextpath/folder/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
```

which apparently don't exist at all. You should have noticed this mistake by just looking at the HTTP traffic monitor in browser's web developer toolset (press F12 in Chrome/Firefox>=23/IE>=9 and check *Network* tab).

You basically need to make those URLs domain-relative, i.e. start with a leading slash:

```
<link href="/contextpath/styles/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextpath/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

or if you worry about the dynamicness of the context path:

```
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/styles/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

but, much better, and actually the canonical JSF way, is to put all those files in `/resources` folder and reference them as JSF resources using `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:outputScript>` according the instructions in the answer to: [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="styles/menu.css" />
<h:outputScript name="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />
```

This way JSF will automatically worry about generating the right URL.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: that manually included jQuery JS file is recipe for trouble given that you're using PrimeFaces. See also the answer to [Adding jQuery to PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeError over all place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined-using-primefaces-f/).