# Primefaces <p:printer> inside a Dialog is not Working in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-9

I am using JSF 2.0 ,Primefaces 3.5 & JBoss Application Server 7.0..

In my `Online Shopping Application`, i am trying to print the details of the Order(My Code).

Everything is working fine in Chrome and FireFox, but in IE9 and above it is throwing an error "Internet Stopped Working" and the print is been failed!

How to fix this issue ?

`Doubt:` Is the issue because of using a Dialog Box. Or is it a Browser compatibility Issue.
Is there any Other Way to Achieve this ?

**My Code:**

*MyController*

```
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class MyController implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void generateOrderList(){

        //Generates the List of Ordered Items 

            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("printOrderDetails.show();");
        }
    }
```

*orderDetails.xhtml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">



  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"   
                  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

            <h:form id="orderForm">

                <h:body class="bgcolor">

<p:panel id="printPnl">
    <h4>Print Order Details</h4>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>

                    <div class="left-panel">
                        <p:commandButton id="orderListCmdBtn" value="Order List" update=":orderForm:printDialog"
                            action="#{myController.generateOrderList()}" />
                    </div>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
</p:panel>

    <p:dialog id="printDialog" header="Get Print" widgetVar="printOrderDetails">

            <div>
                <h:commandButton id="printCmdBtn" value="Print" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print" style="width:50px;float:right">  
                    <p:printer  target="printListPnl"  />
                </h:commandButton> 
            </div>

        <p:panel id="printListPnl">
        <p:panelGrid id="packingListPnlGrd" styleClass="panelgridTable" style="width:100% !important" >
            <p:row>                             
                <p:column styleClass="talign-top" style="width:37%;">
                    To: <br />#{myController.toAddress}&nbsp;
                </p:column>
                <p:column styleClass="talign-top" style="width:37%;">
                    From: <br />#{myController.fromAddress}&nbsp;
                </p:column>

            </p:row>                            
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:dataTable id="orderDtble" var="order" value="#{myController.orderDetails}" >
            <p:columnGroup type="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column headerText="Order Name"></p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Order"></p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Order Date"></p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Remark"></p:column>                                   
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="orderNameOutTxt" value="#{order.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="orderIdOutTxt" value="#{order.orderId}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="orderDateOutTxt" value="#{order.orderDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" type="date" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="orderRemarksOutTxt" value="#{order.remarks}" />
            </p:column>                         
        </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dialog>

    </h:body>

    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

**Updated:**

This is how i had found the way to change the Jquery Version in Primefaces.
[@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined-using-primefaces-f/16168985#16168985).

But i still don't know why the `<p:printer>` doesn't support the IE9 and above, is it just because of JQuery?

***Solved :***

I had Solved this issue, using a `window.open();` and Having a `window.print();` on the content which needs to be printed and ignored by a `CSS` file.Then my Purpose of Print is solved.

But my answer for this Question is not that! Which i am looking for?

Comment: Is there a Way to Update the Jquery File Properties only for the Print Which supports IE9 and Above without effecting the rest of the Application :) @BalusC

Comment: I had found that there is no issue with Printer in IE9 & Above , it is working fine. But the issue with <p:printer> is "Printer inside a Dialog " is not able to Print the Target.Can i know Y ? @BalusC

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to tamper with the `HTTPHeader` being sent to the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" > <!--Top of Page in head-->
```

If `edge` doesn't work try emulating different versions of IE (e.g. *EmulateIE7*), I had the same problem with `inputCalendar`.

Comment: I had a home page Template for the OSA where i had used this "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>" already, but still the issue of Print persist. Do u have any idea of which version of jquery is used in Primefaces 3.5