# How to find jquery selector for p:inputText clearIcon(X button in end)

Tags: jquery, html, css, primefaces

[Please look this image and cross button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIuHq.png) I have a search form, that has input field using primefaces

```
<p:inputText required="true" placeholder="#{cc.attrs.searchTip}" value="#{cc.attrs.queryProperty}" />
```

As you can see, I am using composite:attribute. I want an action attached to this cross button(X button appears on the right side of input field).

I used firebug to see the cross button id. it shows something like this:

```
<a class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" href="#"></a>
```

So I wrote a jquery code to test and show alert

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all").click(function(){
        alert("The cross button was clicked.");
    });
});
```

And it fails :(

Comment: What is your functional requirement? Looks weird to me trying to hook a jquery click event to a Primefaces based user interface.

Comment: One issue is that the $ shortcut has been removed by PF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place

Comment: @NullPtr92065: This is (as stated in your other answer) **not** the case. What is the problem here is that the OP does not know how plain css selectors work... If you have a `class="a b c"`, then the selector should be ".a.b.c" as can be read in all kinds of css totorials (I'll re-tag the question and you'll see an answer appearing'

Comment: @Sandra: 'it fails' is not 'smart', (specific, measurable... etc) and it can lead to unsubstantiated comments. What you did good is to post the client-side html, but you forgot to also add the css and html tag to this question (that is where the issue is) See https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select an element with multiple classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're selecting multiple classes with jQuery you can't do:

```
$(".ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all")
```

Spaces in a jQuery selector look for matches in descendants. In addition, because the descendants aren't prefixed with a `.` jQuery would actually be looking for an element with that name. That selector would be searching for something like this:

```
<div class='ui-input-clear'>
  <ui-btn>
    <ui-icon-delete>
      <ui-btn-icon-notext>
        <ui-corner-all> //Match here
```

You need to separate the classes with a `.` so jQuery will look for each individual class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-input-clear.ui-btn.ui-icon-delete.ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-corner-all").click(function(){
        alert("The cross button was clicked.");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6p1n1tta/

Comment: The answer is good in that it solves the problem. There is a fluke in it however. The original selector does _not_ search for a single class. The second part, 'ui-btn', is is interpreted as a descendant element with that name, as are the ones after that. Which obiously do not exist (unless maybe you are styling xml instead of html). And it is a duplicate question then btw

Comment: You're right, I'll update that portion of the answer.

Comment: Wrong again... it is not about classes of descendent elements but their **name**... `<div class='ui-input-clear'><ui-btn><ui-icon-delete><ui-btn-icon-notext><ui-corner-all>...`

Comment: Try putting `<div class="ui-input-clear"><ui-btn>Not this<ui-icon-delete>Or this<ui-btn-icon-notext>Or this <ui-corner-all>But This</ui-corner-all></ui-btn-icon-notext></ui-icon-delete></ui-btn></div>` in the html of your jsffiddle and remove all but the first `. ` in the selector. And be surprised...