# ajax stop working on close event primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I got panel with closeable property and rendered property. At first, the panel rendered is false, so it's not shown.

After I clicked command Button,  the panel rendered is set to true (in my bean it named isShowChat) and the panel appeared.
When I close that panel, every ajax run in that window closed.

Here's my xhtml code :

```
<h:form id="live-chat">
   <p:panelGrid class="panel-content" columns="2" columnClasses="form-right,form-left" id="live-chat-panelgrid">
       <p:panel style="min-width: 500px; height: 500px;" >
          <p:panel header="#{liveChatMBean.agent.name}" closable="true" rendered="#{liveChatMBean.isShowChat}">
              <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{liveChatMBean.onClose}" />
          </p:panel>
       </p:panel>
   </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Here's my onClose method on backing bean :

```
public void onClose(CloseEvent event) {
    isShowChat = false;
}
```

I don't know why when I triggered onClose listener, every ajax run in there is stop.

Have you guys face this problem? Thanks for your help.

Update :
Sorry I forgot to tell there's error in firebug.
[image: in firebug]

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: @JasperdeVries yeah jquery from primefaces got error. I've updated my thread

Comment: Are you loading two different versions of jQuery by accident?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place