# Primefaces prevents other components from rendering

Tags: javascript, primefaces

When I include PrimeFaces into my web-application, some other components just refuse to render on the client's browser. I don't find the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console? Do you have conflicting jQuery versions? (PF loads its own jQuery)

Comment: See http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding jQuery to PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeError over all place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place)

Comment: So there were errors. Thank you for taking the time to respond to questions in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the PrimeFaces' dependencies that are manifold. 
Most likely it is due to the fact that your components rely on jQuery and PrimeFaces brings its own jQuery, which causes a clash of the versions.