# When I add jQuery, selectOneMenu dosn't work

Tags: jquery, primefaces, selectonemenu

this is selectOneMenu initialize from DB

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try to share your code here & tell us what do you mean by "add jQuery"?

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Why do you "add jQuery" when you are using PrimeFaces (which could be found from having a look at a picture of code which should have been posted as text)?

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place

Comment: Code in text please not images

Comment: OK thanks ,this is my code as a text

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces has already Jquery, so you don't have to include it again. 
Moreover, Primefaces 6.1, for example, use jquery 2.2.4 version. So you cannot add Jquery version 3.
[Primefaces 6.1.1 release](https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-6-1-1-released/)