# how to transition PrimeFaces outputlabel

Tags: css, primefaces

I want to make PrimeFaces like outputlabel and inputtext i like Google user input. When I do the following example for html, I don't encounter any problems, it just doesn't work when I want to implement it for PrimeFaces. How can I solve this problem?

The problem appears more clearly below

Although the first inputtext is not yet focus

But the second inputtext title appears in the middle

[image]

This is where I'm having trouble.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.label-before, .field input:valid + label::before, .field input:focus + label::before {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 6px;
  left: 9px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px 10%;
}

.field {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.field label::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 300ms all;
}
.field input {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #222;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.field input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: blue;
}
.field input:valid + label::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
}
.field input:focus + label::before {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="field">
    <input type="password" required autocomplete="off" id="password">
    <label for="password" title="Şifrenizi girin" data-title="Şifre"></label>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: _"Google user input"_ changes every year... And indeed, what is not working? Why the PF inputText and not a plain jsf one (that produces a plain html one)... Sounds like an overly complex thing to do

Comment: Don't load your own jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place

Comment: @JasperdeVries There is no problem with the console. It just doesn't look like the example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: my problem is not override css. How do I adapt sample css i primefaces. I hope I can explain my problem @JasperdeVries

Comment: Hey, I'm just trying to help here.. I'm surprised to see downvotes on some of my older questions. FYI I did not downvote yours. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] so we can help you further.

Comment: I did not do. I'm just looking for the answer to my question.

Comment: I did not downvote either, but as it now stands, the question and answer are not very useful. And @JasperdeVries is right, the basic question is about overriding PrimeFaces CSS! But like stated, **why do you want to override the PF controls if for this case you could use the basic JSF controls wihout much hashle**. Adding a `jsf:id` to the controls and declaring the namespace would have most likely make it work for you. Overly complex solution now.... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the jQuery Floating Placeholder Text Plugin - Placeholder Label 
Thanks