# How to colour based on status value ( Passed/Failed) in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jquery, css, primefaces

I am trying to set the color based on column status value ( Passed/Failed/InProgress) using jQuery.

I have copied the table and pasted in jsfiddle to try that and there is working. However, In the actual XHTML file, jQuery is not working.

**.xhtml**

```
    <ui:composition template="/pages/layout.xhtml">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('tr > td.y_n').each(function() {
              colsole.log("in function");
            if ($(this).text() === "Passed") {
                colsole.log("in if");
              $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
            } else {
                colsole.log("in if else");
              $(this).css('background-color', '#3AC709');
            }
          });
        });


    </script>

    <p:dataTable id="idExecution" var="varTS" value="#{executionBean.lstLiveSelectedSuiteData}" style="margin-bottom:20px">

<f:facet name="header"> Steps </f:facet>

<p:column headerText="Status" class="y_n" >
        <h:outputText value="#{varTS.status}"  />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Error Message">
      <h:outputText value="#{varTS.errorMessage}" />
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
 </ui:composition>
```

Note: given HTML in the jsfiddle are copied runtime data. (xhtml > html)

http://jsfiddle.net/z2ty0q8k/

I am expecting color change based on status column value

Comment: Why you don't use
Primefaces Datatable RowColor 
 https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml

Comment: I tried this also, `<p:column headerText="Status" styleClass="#{varTS.status}" >
<h:outputText value="#{varTS.status}"  /></p:column>` and css `.Passed { 
    background-color: green; !important;
}

.Failed {
    background-color: red; !important;
}

.InProgress{
 background-color: white; !important;
}` but not working

Comment: And please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place

Comment: @JasperdeVries tried but no luck

Comment: @tsotzolas followed the link but no luck there also

Comment: 'no luck' is not a description of a developer with a problem. It is something a poker player would say in Las-Vegas ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's better to use [Primefaces Datatable RowColor](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml)
First of all, you must make styleclass in css.

---

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.passed {
    background-color: red !important;
}
.inProgress {
    background-color: green !important;
}   
</style>
```

---

Then you must use in datatable the `rowStyleClass` (this is wrong in your code)

```
<p:dataTable var="var" value="#{someBean.dataList}" rowStyleClass="#{someBean.checkStatus(var.status)}">
<p:column headerText="Id">
    <h:outputText value="#{var.id}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Status">
    <h:outputText value="#{var.status}" />
</p:column>
.
.
.
</p:dataTable>
```

For Checking the status you can make in ManageBean  a method  or use something like primefaces example with inline if statement:

```
    public String checkStatus(String status){
    if (status.equals("InProgress")) {
        //This is the styleClass in css
        return "inProgress";
    } else if (status.equals("Passed")){
        //This is the styleClass in css
        return "passed";
    }else{
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried `<p:column headerText="Status" styleClass="#{varTS.status}" >` and added CSS which you provided. However, I was still not getting what I am expecting and then found that the updated CSS code was not updated in chrome resource tab (Cache problem). so Hard refresh the page and then working. Accepting the answer.