# Primefaces Input Text set value

Tags: jquery, primefaces

Primefaces InputText; I want to set its value with jQuery. This is the input text in the xhtml page :

```
<p:inputText value="#{Bean.numOfVisibleRows}" id="hidNumOfVisibleRows" widgetVar="hidNumOfVisibleRows_WV" type="text">
```

And this is the javascript i tried to change its value:

```
var numOfVisibleRows = 10;
PF('hidNumOfVisibleRows_WV').setValue(numOfVisibleRows);
```

but I get an error : Uncaught TypeError: PF(...).setValue is not a function ...

How can i do that?
thanks!

Comment: How did you load jQuery?

Comment: Check this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp you should be using val() function

Comment: But also keep this in mind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerrors

Comment: i load jquery using the folder resources/primefaces/jquery  (jQuery v3.3.1)

Comment: PF('hidNumOfVisibleRows_WV').setValue(numOfVisibleRows) is the right syntax to set value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding jQuery to PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerrors)

Comment: Don't load jQuery manually. PrimeFaces will load it. If you load your own you run into type errors.