# Reordering a row in a p:dataTable results in a javascript "Uncaught Type Error: this.tbody.sortable is not a function"

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am a beginner to promefaces.
I have a data table

```
p:dataTable draggableRows="true" editable="true"
```

however it does not really work and I can see the following javascript error in my explorer-developer's tool:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.tbody.sortable is not a function
    makeRowsDraggable http://localhost:8080/test_app/app/javax.faces.resource/components.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:12
    init http://localhost:8080/test_app/app/javax.faces.resource/components.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:12
    Class.extend/e[d]</< http://localhost:8080/test_app/app/javax.faces.resource/core.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:5
    c http://localhost:8080/test_app/app/javax.faces.resource/core.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:5
    createWidget http://localhost:8080/test_app/app/javax.faces.resource/core.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:1
    cw http://localhost:8080/test_app/app/javax.faces.resource/core.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:1
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/test_app/app/suche?execution=e2s4:178
```

Do I need to link jquery or something else?
I use following taglibs:

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
```

Comment: Hi, 1: it is PrimeFaces, not promefaces, 2 [ask] states to create a [mcve]. 3: Always post version info explicitly (although it can be deduced from the error indirectly). 4: Tried a more recent version like PF 8?. 5: I improved the title

Comment: Do you load your own jQuery library?

Comment: @JasperdeVries yes I use Jquery 3.4.1 and tinyMCE 4.7.11, Primefaces 8.0

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you so much ... I already use PF 8

Comment: uhhh.... the logging/error says 6.1, maybe you have two PrimeFaces jars in your runtime project. Amd don't manually include a jquery version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually adding / loading jQuery with PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/manually-adding-loading-jquery-with-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerrors)

Comment: oh, and you might want to consider using https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf if you want / need JSF integration out of the box.

Comment: Any feedback? (you were online 24 minutes ago)

Comment: @Kukeltje I am trying the last two remmended post from Jasper de Vries ... the other jquery (the one which added manually) actually added by a template, which I can not change ... I use a template for the whole project and everything is fine but in only one file I need to use PF table .

Comment: Then you are just lucky you don't have similar prpblems on other pages...  and it is stilll very weird (and you did not comment on this) that the logging says you use PF 6.1 and you claim to use 8.0... cheers

Comment: @Kukeltje I used PF 6.1 and at that time I copied the exception afterward I upgrade it to PF 8.0 but it still does not help. I just send the older version of Exception but I used the PF 8.0 . by the way none of them working

Comment: Why can't you change the template? That does not sound very flexible. If someone at your company is responsible for the template have them read the duplicate I've linked.

Comment: It sounds wierd but in old version the same setting worked fine, I only upgarde the template and in upgraded version we have jquery 3.4 and now it does not work any more