# Upgrade Primefaces from 6.2 to 7.0.14 in Maven

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces

In my project im using primefaces 6.2, in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

It has [security issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5807) with the jquery it is using, it is [fixed in 7.0.14](https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-7-0-14-and-8-0-2-released/) so i wish to upgrade primefaces to `7.0.14`, but in maven repository, i only see all the major versions:

[image]

How can i upgrade to 7.0.14 using maven?

Comment: I don't think primefaces let specific versions available for free. Either you use their final or RC versions available on their own [repository](https://repository.primefaces.org/) or you pay subscription. See on their download page: https://www.primefaces.org/downloads/

Comment: @JorgeCampos is correct. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/manually-adding-loading-jquery-with-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerrors for a different solution

Comment: Just upgrade to PrimeFaces 8. And as soon as 9 is out, upgrade to 9. See https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=63144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrimeFaces 7.0.14 is for Elite members only who pay a subscription of 99$ a year for support. They have access to the private release versions like 7.0.X.

On Maven Central are only the community versions 6.2, 7.0, 8.0 etc.

So you will need an Elite subscription to get this fix in 7.0.14 or 8.0.2.... or you will have to wait until PF 9.0 is released to get this fix.

Comment: Yes, we have the Elite subscription, so for any of these non-public releases, I have to download the jar from the Primefaces support page and import it into my Maven repository.