# Warn user when form contains unsaved data, ignoring data table filter fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, jquery-selectors

I'm searching for a way to warn the user that inside the form is unsaved data.
The warning should appear if the user navigates to another site or if he closes the browser.
I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709356/warn-user-of-unsaved-data-in-jsf) which kind of works. Sometimes it does not react if browser gets closed.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Set the unload message whenever any input element get changed.
        $(':input').change(function() {
            setConfirmUnload(true);
        });

        // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly.
        $('form').submit(function() {
            setConfirmUnload(false);
        });
    });

    function setConfirmUnload(on) {
        var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?";
        window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null;
    }
</script>
```

Now I have one Problem.
I've got a `<p:datatable>` on my page. Each column has a filter field. Since this field is also a input field the selector also matches if something is in the filter field.
Is it possible to avoid that the selector checks the filter fields.

Comment: Sure, by improving the jquery selector that now has ':input'

Comment: Why do you manually load jQuery? See [Adding jQuery to PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeError over all place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place)

Comment: @JasperdeVries I didn't changed anything it's an example form BalusC

Comment: I didn't say you did. I'm sure PrimeFaces wasn't used in that question. You are using PrimeFaces. Just pointing out that manually loading jQuery is not needed and will likely get you into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you are looking for is `:input:not(.ui-column-filter)` (data table filter inputs have a `ui-column-filter` class). You can simply inspect those fields in your browser and see what classes are set. In Chrome right-click a field and select "Inspect".

So change this line:

```
$(':input').change(function() {
```

to:

```
$(':input:not(.ui-column-filter)').change(function() {
```

You can test both selectors in your JavaScript console and see the difference.

See also:

- https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Additionally, you should eliminate the script that loads jQuery. jQuery is bundled with PrimeFaces and is loaded when when you use PrimeFaces components on a page. [Multiple instances of jQuery will cause uncaught type errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place).

Comment: @TheNewby Please note I've changed the order of the selector. The result is the same, but it's faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a more specific selector instead of `$(':input')`
If the datatable is not inside the form tag you can do something like `$('form :input')`. Or you can use the `.not()` method to exclude specific elements.